# Magento 2: Customer logout after minicart showing product

Tags: mini-cart, magento2.2.4

I have facing issue in Magento ver. 2.2.4 while customer logout then still showing product to the cart.

**Actual Result:**

Step 1) Login to the customer.

Step 2) Add product to the minicart.

Step 3) Logout the current customer.

Step 4) Still display product in minicart

**Expected Result:**

After Logout the customer minicart should be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find for fix the issue using **"Clear Persistence on Sign Out" >> Yes**

Magento Admin Path:

Stores >> Configuration >> CUSTOMERS >> Persistent Shopping Cart >> General Options >> Clear Persistence on Sign Out : No to Yes

Answer (score 2):

You have an issue at Private content fetch.

The private content like **customer data cart, wishlist, customer data** is specific to individual users, it’s ***reasonable to handle it on the client***.

Use our customer-data JS library to store private data in local storage and show at
your browser.

See how  [**Magento2 implement Private content**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html)

So, it means when you have logout then private content taking time to update.

***Also check the Request Url is cache from the server End.***

Please check this two factory and you get a clue about the issue from this.

Comment: As per suggestion you are right. But after checking I have facing issue in "Clear Persistence on Sign Out" set as No. I have set to Yes. After issue has fixed. Thanks for help.